# How to emit continuous event on button down in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game, where if I want to move for example to the left, I have to click and hold certain button. But the button makes action only once and to do it again I have to press it again. I would like to do this action for as long as I am holding this button. Sorry for this newbie question.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LAndroidMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float sidewaysForce = 25f;  // Variable that determines the sideways force
    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnPointerDown()` and `OnPointerUp()` like shown here https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/touch-and-hold-a-button-on-new-ui.266065/

Answer (score 0):

#### Edited

You can use the **[Input.GetMouseButtonDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html)** event inside an update loop :

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehavior {

    void Update() {

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            // Trigger your event here.
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work, If I use this I still have to tap the button multiple times